# messy appearance of scheduled notifications

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

i am working on scheduled notifications application, am trying to fire just 4 notifications related to 4 alarms(cal,cal2,cal3,cal4)

the problem is that every time i run the application, i don't get all the four notifications.

i wrote the sequence of appearance of the 4 notifications, running the application 6 times.

124

4

3 4 note: i hear like two tones runing when displaying 3 as well 4, its like firing two notifications at the same time but displaying only one.

4

4

4

this is my code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.DATE,27);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,11);
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,2015);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,56);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

        Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal2.set(Calendar.DATE,27);
        cal2.set(Calendar.MONTH,11);
        cal2.set(Calendar.YEAR,2015);
        cal2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
        cal2.set(Calendar.MINUTE,56);
        cal2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 20);

        Calendar cal3 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal3.set(Calendar.DATE,27);
        cal3.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11);
        cal3.set(Calendar.YEAR,2015);
        cal3.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
        cal3.set(Calendar.MINUTE,56);
        cal3.set(Calendar.SECOND, 30);

        Calendar cal4 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal4.set(Calendar.DATE,27);
        cal4.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11);
        cal4.set(Calendar.YEAR,2015);
        cal4.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
        cal4.set(Calendar.MINUTE,56);
        cal4.set(Calendar.SECOND, 40);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)  getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
      Intent alertIntent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);

        alertIntent.putExtra("Notification Key", 1);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

        alertIntent.putExtra("Notification Key", 2);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal2.getTimeInMillis(), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 2, alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

        alertIntent.putExtra("Notification Key", 3);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal3.getTimeInMillis(), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 3, alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

        alertIntent.putExtra("Notification Key", 4);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal4.getTimeInMillis(), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 4, alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

this is the `OnReceive` code:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        Integer notificationId  = intent.getIntExtra("Notification Key", -1);
        switch(notificationId){
            case 1:
                createNotification(context, "title1", "event1", "event of today");
                break;
            case 2:
                createNotification(context, "title2", "event2", "event of today");
                break;
            case 3:
                createNotification(context, "title3", "event3", "event of today");
                break;
            case 4:
                createNotification(context, "title4", "event4", "event of today");
                break;
        }


           }

    public void createNotification(Context context, String msg, String msgText, String msgAlert) {
        PendingIntent notificIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.not)
                .setContentTitle(msg)
                .setTicker(msgAlert)
                .setContentText(msgText);
        //intent to fire when notification clicked on
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(notificIntent);
        //how the person will be notified
        mBuilder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        //cancel notification when clicked in the taskbar
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager= (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


       mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the developers website,

> To set up a notification so it can be updated, issue it with a notification ID by calling NotificationManager.notify(). To update this notification once you've issued it, update or create a NotificationCompat.Builder object, build a Notification object from it, and issue the Notification with the same ID you used previously. If the previous notification is still visible, the system updates it from the contents of the Notification object. If the previous notification has been dismissed, a new notification is created instead.

So either ensure that you read/delete the notification before you receive the new one. Or create each notification with different id.

moreover, if you would read about alarm manager, they say that from api 21 ( i think), the set() is now an inexact call. So it is possible that your alarm is not instantly fired away. The issue with this would be that since the ID in your pending intent is always same, the alarm manager will remove/update the existing alarms and then only will it issue the new alarm in the system.

Comment: i tried to give each notification unique ID using  mNotificationManager.notify(random_number, mBuilder.build()); but the still get messy appearance as mentioned above

Comment: another possibility, as mentioned in updated answer, is that your alarm is not getting fired away instantly. try setting setExact() or rather give different ids in your pending intent instead of 0

Comment: i cant use setExact becuase my minimum api is 16, so i cant use it in api16, and about the pending intent id, what you suggest as a solution?

Comment: try giving different id to your pending intents like 1,2,3,4 instead of always giving 0. Mostly it should work.

And just for the information, you can use setExact. Just use if-else statement where you use setExact if your Build.Version>21

Comment: got it about the if-else, i used it before in another application,thanks, but can i as you to write the code of the pending intents with different id, i cant understand what you mean exactly, edit your answer writing the code of pending intents

Comment: try giving random IDs here: 

PendingIntent notificIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, ID_HERE, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);


And also for your notification. Other than this, right now I cant see any issue with the code

Comment: thanks alot @Rusheel Jain , i posted the answer, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with API, i was testing my application on android with API 19, this API don't get `set` , it needs `setExact`, so i made `if` statement to check whether to use `set` if the API is less than 19, and `setExact` for API 19 and above.

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (currentapiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
    // Do something for Kitkat and above versions
} else{
    // do something for phones running an SDK before Kitkat
}
```